# Why are the scatter plot points so big?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's my ggplot command:

```
  ggplot(data,aes(x=first,y=Grade,col=factor(Stage))) + 
    geom_point(size = 1) + 
    geom_jitter() + 
    facet_wrap(~ Assignment)
```

It produces a b bunch of plots like this one, but notice how the dots are too big. I've tried adding size= in different places and it only makes the dots bigger! Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: you only need to use one of geom_jitter or geom_point

Comment: In addition, have you tried a fractional size like `size = 0.1` or making use of alpha transparency, e.g. `alpha=.3`? Check out these strategies http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_point.html#overplotting

Comment: @rawr: intersting, so geom_jitter is just like geom_point, except it jitters?

Comment: @lukA Thanks... I thought I had tried it but I must not have because I just did and it worked. Odd that the default seems larger than what I've seen in examples etc. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This did it:

```
  ggplot(data,aes(x=first,y=Grade,col=factor(Stage))) + 
    geom_jitter(size= 0.5) + 
    facet_wrap(~ Assignment)
```